# "str = str.replace("something", "something_else")" not working in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python

When I enter the following:

```
str = str.replace("something", "something_else")
```

It returns with:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I am on Python 3.6.5. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your variable `str` is a tuple, not a string.

Comment: Also, `str` is a bad variable name to pick, because the `str` built-in type is already using that name.

Comment: Are you trying to replace all occurrences of "something" wth "something_else" in a tuple of strings?

Comment: Please post your whole code, not just a single line with no context.

Answer (score -2):

Check the content of `str`.  It contains a tuple, not a string.  Is it the output from a `.split()` operation or suchlike?

For example:

```
>>> str = ( 'a', 'b', 'banana' )
>>> str.replace("something", "something_else")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Obviously it *does* work with the correct `str`:

```
>>> str = 'banana' 
>>> str.replace("something", "something_else")
>>>
```